# Realm.io RealmSwift Other Realms Migration

Tags: xcode, swift2, realm, realm-migration

I need to do a migration for my `Other Realm` .

I get my realm path via this method (`AppDelegate`). If a user logged in before, i will retrieve the user's realm else i will just use the `Default Realm`.

```
 func getRealmPath() -> String {
    let preferences : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults()
    let username = preferences.objectForKey(usernameKey) as! String?

    if username != nil {
        let realmName =  ("\(username!).realm")

        print("RealmName: \(realmName)", terminator: "")

        let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        return documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent(realmName)
    }else{
        return Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!
    }  
}
```

I did my migration via this method (called inside `AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) .

```
func updateRealm(){

    let config = Realm.Configuration(path: getRealmPath(), schemaVersion: 2, migrationBlock: { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) -> Void in

        print("oldSchemaVersion \(oldSchemaVersion)") 

         migration.create("RLMStringTimestamp", value: ["pKey": NSUUID().UUIDString, "value": "", "updatedAt": NSDate(), "createdAt": NSDate(), "deletedAt": Date().getInitDate(), "updatedBy" : " ", "syncedAt": NSDate() ])           

        if oldSchemaVersion < 2  {

           //MIGRATION
           let firstNameTimeStamp =  RLMStringTimestamp(newValue: oldObject!["firstName"] as? String)
           migration.create("RLMStringTimestamp", value: firstNameTimeStamp)
           newObject!["firstName"] = firstNameTimeStamp

        }
      }

      Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

      //EDIT 2 
      Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path = getRealmPath()

     //EDIT 1
     //<strike>let realm = try! Realm(path: getRealmPath())</strike>

     //EDIT 4 
     print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration)

     //EDIT 3
     let realm = try! Realm()
     }
```

> For my RLMCustomer Object, i modified `var firstName: String = ""` to `var firstName: RLMStringTimeStamp!`

<strike>Even if i change the `schemaVersion` to something very high, the `migrationBlock` didn't get call. Can anyone help me spot what am i missing or doing wrong?</strike>

After running the app, it crashes with `bad excess, code = 257`

EDIT 1:

> error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1." UserInfo=0x170660c00 {NSLocalizedDescription=Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 1.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 50

<strike>It seems to be reading the wrong configuration file and i suspect the error is due to `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config` How do i set the configuration for `Other Realm`?</strike>

EDIT 2:

> I make my `default realm` to contains the name and path of my `other realm`

EDIT 4:

It seems that the configuration file is correct. I am able to run the app without problem if there's no customer record from the old realm. It will only crash when there's customer record in the old realm. I can get the values from the `oldObject["firstName"]`

`print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration)`

> Realm.Configuration {
>       path = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8670C084-75E7-4955-89FB-137620C9B00D/Documents/perwyl.realm;
>       inMemoryIdentifier = (null);
>       encryptionKey = (null);
>       readOnly = 0;
>       schemaVersion = 2;
>       migrationBlock = <**NSMallocBlock**: 0x170451220>;
>       dynamic = 0;
>       customSchema = (null);
>   }
>   oldSchemaVersion 0

Much Thanks!!!

EDIT 5: Solution to my problem

> I'm not sure why it crashes if i assign `StringTimestamp object` directly to newObject.

```
let firstName = (oldObject!["firstName"] as? String)!
let firstNameTimeStamp =  StringTimestamp(newValue: firstName)
let testName = migration.create("StringTimestamp",value:     firstNameTimeStamp)
newObject!["firstName"] = firstNameTimeStamp //Crashes
newObject!["firstName"] = testName //works
```

Thanks for everyone's guidelines! :)

Comment: The migrations are called when the file is opened, which happens in your case as soon as you retrieve the default realm. Could you show the code how you're doing that as well?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to instantiate a _realm_?

Comment: @Edman i have edited my qn. pls take a look

Comment: So _realm_ instantiation works now? What error are you getting this time? Have a look at the [docs on migration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#performing-a-migration). The `newObject` can be accessed inside a closure passed to `migration.enumerate(RLMCustomer.className())`.

Comment: @Edman I am still getting the same error. I've extract out the migration code to `https://github.com/perwyl/RealmMigrationTest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not letting *realm* use the default configuration? Since you set the path in default configuration to `getRealmPath()`, it should be ok to do just:

```
 let realm = try! Realm()
```

By instantiating the *realm* with `Realm(path: getRealmPath())` you are overriding the `defaultConfiguration` you had previously set. That is, the path of the realm becomes `getRealmPath()`, but all other properties you set in `config` are lost, and default values are used instead. This includes `schemaVersion = 0` and `migrationBlock = nil`.

The intent of initializers like `Realm(path:)` and `Realm(configuration:)` is to allow you to use alternative configurations other than the default. If what you want is to use a modified version of the default configuration, then you would need to do something on the lines of:

```
// Get a copy of the default configuration
var otherConfig = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
// Update the copy with what you need
otherConfig.path = "/some/path/otherRealm.realm"
// Use the updated configuration to instantiate a realm
let otherRealm = try! Realm(configuration: otherConfig)
```

One neat way to debug *realm configuration* problems is by setting breakpoints or printing logs before instantiating the *realm*. Running the following code lets me know what is the default configuration about to be used.

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration))
let realm = try! Realm()
```

The output looks something like

```
Realm.Configuration {
    path = /Users/<full-path-omitted>/edman.realm;
    schemaVersion = 2;
    migrationBlock = <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7faee04ac590>;
    // other properties...
}
```

By looking at it I'm sure my *realm* was instantiated with the path for `edman.realm`, `schemaVersion = 2`, and it has non-nil `migrationBlock`.

Comment: hi @edman thanks for the reply. I tried ` let realm = try! Realm()` , it crashes with the same error.

Comment: @perwyl it's hard to help you much further without access to your code. I copied the code you provided and it works in my project. The log output in my answer was made with your code. A possible cause for your problem is some race condition. You may be trying to instantiate realm before setting its `defaultConfiguration`. I have updated the answer with some tips I like to use. Let me know if you have more information that might help us solve your problem.

Comment: ```Realm.Configuration {
 path = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D6CD93A5-AEBF-45FC-B7BD-46DCBC21066F/Documents/perwyl.realm;
 inMemoryIdentifier = (null);
 encryptionKey = (null);
 readOnly = 0;
 schemaVersion = 2;
 migrationBlock = <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x170447320>;
 dynamic = 0;
 customSchema = (null);
}``` my oldSchemaVersion is 0. If the old realm is empty, no error will throw, it will only crash if i had a old Customer record. `RLMStringTimestamp` is a newly created object in schemaVersion 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the schema version to a larger value in your realm configuration whenever your schema is updated. That is, in your `updateRealm()` function

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    path: getRealmPath(),
    schemaVersion: 3, // any value larger than previous version
    migrationBlock: { /* ... */}
})

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
let realm = try! Realm()
```

From the [*realm docs*](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#performing-a-migration).

> You define a migration and the associated schema version by setting
>   `Realm.Configuration.schemaVersion` and
>   `Realm.Configuration.migrationBlock`.
>
> When creating a Realm with this configuration, the migration block will be applied *to update the Realm to the given schema version* if a migration is needed.

You correctly set the migration block, but you don't update the schema version. This is why the migration block is not being executed, although it is provided in your configuration.

A difference between the version in disk and the version in your configuration is what triggers `migrationBlock`.

Comment: Hi @Edman, I updated my schema version and the crash only occurs if i assign StringTimestamp to `newObject`, the other migration works fine (Int, String etc). Could it be because StringTimestamp object does not exist in the older version?

Comment: @perwyl I couldn't reproduce your problem modifying your [github project](https://github.com/perwyl/RealmMigrationTest). Both using `firstNameTimeStamp` or `testName` worked well there. I'm also not sure you're still having problems. If so, can you update that github project with your current problem? If your problem is fixed consider accepting or upvoting my answers.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 Solution

```
class func realmConfigs(_ realmName: String) -> RealmSwift.Realm.Configuration?{
    var config = Realm.Configuration()
    config.readOnly = true
    // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
    let fileURLString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: realmName, ofType: "realm")
    guard fileURLString != nil else {
        return nil
    }
    config.fileURL = URL(string: fileURLString!)
    config.schemaVersion = UInt64(1.0)
    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm

    return config
}
```

and will be used like this

```
    var realm : Realm?
    do{

        let config = realmConfigs("FILE_NAME")
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config!
        realm = try Realm(fileURL: realmURL)
    }
    catch {
        print("Opening realm file error: \(error)")
    }
```